# Why is my back to top button not going to the top when clicked?

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop

```
  // ===== Scroll to Top ==== 
         $(window).scroll(function() {
             if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) { // If page is scrolled more than 50px
                 $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200); // Fade in the arrow
             } else {
                 $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200); // Else fade out the arrow
             }
         });
         $('#return-to-top').click(function() { // When arrow is clicked
             $('body,html').animate({
                 scrollTop: 0 // Scroll to top of body
             }, 500);
         });
```

Whenever I click the button it does not bring you to the top. It just won't do anything. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is the css: http://pastebin.com/1SF4S6Vg

Comment: can u just put your in jsfiddle and give us the link that could be usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct as I've recreated in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/ChDdE/1118/). I'm guessing you are missing a `.ready()` around your function. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) { // If page is scrolled more than 50px
            $('#return-to-top').fadeIn(200); // Fade in the arrow
        } else {
            $('#return-to-top').fadeOut(200); // Else fade out the arrow
        }
    });
    $('#return-to-top').click(function () { // When arrow is clicked
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0 // Scroll to top of body
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't have to put the `.scroll()` function inside the `.ready()` function. Btw I think your first rule should look like this: `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: `$(function() {...` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {...`

Answer (score 0):

Just as @Tomanow answered, using `$(function () {...}` makes it work. If not, you need additional `#top` tag (or some other anchors) when calling this function, this also works, but will display `#top` in the link after you click.